# Conditional functions or multiple similar definitions?

Tags: c++, callback

In my program(C++), I'm going to use callback functions to process input from the keyboard and mouse and constantly draw a scene. How these functions process information will change depending on the state of the program; like I would have certain functionality assigned to several keys, say the arrow keys move the highlighter in the main screen, but I want their functionality to change in another screen. I'm using OpenGL with GLUT, and it's possible to change the keyboard function for example by assigning a different function pointer to it.

The method I used in the past was to define multiple processing functions, each one for a specific task. For example, I have a keyboard for the main menu, but when a different screen is viewed, the function is changed by assigning the appropriate function pointer:

```
glutKeyboardFunction(MainMenueKeyboardFuncPtr);
```

But now, I'm wondering if using conditional statements within one function is a better approach.

**My question** is: are there any performance issues with the conditional functions approach? I'm thinking to define a single function, say for the keyboard, to process keyboard input in all situations:

```
void KeyInputProcess(int key)
{
   select(SCREEN)
 {

   case MAIN_SCREEN:

  select(key)
   {
 /*process input*/
   }
   break;

    case OPTIONS_SCREEN:

     select(key)
     {
      /*process differently from MAIN_SCREEN*/
     }
     break;
 }



}
```

Would the checking that takes place every time the function is called have a significant impact on the performance? Which approach is better if I want to maximize performance?

Comment: It's C++. I changed the tag and I'll add it in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: are there any performance issues with the conditional functions approach?

In a word: no.

The additional performance cost is an extra `select` statement, whose cost probably depends on the number of `switch` options in the `select`.

I say "no" because I expect that the performance cost for a few extra instructions is measured in nanoseconds: and there aren't enough keystrokes per second for that to make a difference. Also the actual work you do (i.e. calling OpenGL functions) is probably/hopefully more significant than the performance of the code required to get there; it's like, "Q: Is calling a subroutine expensive? A: Probably not as expensive as executing/running the subroutine."

The befit of using "function pointers" (or perhaps a different subclass for each screen) is more to do with the code's maintainability and readability: for example, it would let you have different people creating each screen; to be contrasted with having a single KeyInputProcess function, where all handling for every screen is defined in the same function.

Taking the trouble to create an abstract base class for a screen (with concrete subclasses for specific screens, and a virtual KeyInputProcess method) may make more code more maintainable (easier to add new functionality without changing existing functionality, nor requiring previously-simple methods to become too complicated)
On the other hand, for a smaller project with one programmer, defining many abstract and concrete classes might be '[over-engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering)' (the Wikipedia article for over-engineering says, "See also: [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)"). Beware that if you practice YAGNI then, later when you do need it, you ought to be good at refactoring: i.e. adding structure later to previously less-structured code, where I'd regard "conditional statements within one function" as 'less structured' and "abstract base class with subclasses" as 'more structured'.

> Which approach is better if I want to maximize performance?

Possibly a function pointer: because it's only one or two opcodes to dispatch to the right function, instead of testing several switch statements (assuming that the compiler implements `select` as "if else if else if else if").

It's also possible that a function pointer isn't as fast: it dispatches to a different location i the code, which may cause slowness due to memory pages and CPU caching; whereas instead a monolithic KeyInputProcess function might have all its code located on the same page of memory.

In either case I doubt whether the performance difference is significant in this case (handling keystrokes).

Answer (score 2):

> are there any performance issues with the conditional functions approach?

No.

> Would the checking that takes place every time the function is called have a significant impact on the performance?

No

> Which approach is better if I want to maximize performance?

Insignificant difference.

But neither is the method I would use (not for performance but for maintenance).
I would either change the callback used by GLUT as the screen changed, or I would pick the function from a vector:

```
typedef void (*KEYINPUTPROCESS)(int);
KEYINPUTPROCESS  keyboardProcessingFunctions[] = {
    KeyInputProcessMain, 
    KeyInputProcessMainOptions
};

void KeyInputProcess(int key)
{
    KEYINPUTPROCESS procFunc = keyboardProcessingFunctions[SCREEN];
    return procFunc(key);
}
```